# Magento 2 boilerplate themes

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, less-css

Are here any Magento 2 boilerplate themes out there ? I am looking for some **starter** themes which have the basic structuring and extended files in place.

Answer (score 3):

So far I found only one such theme by [Studioemma](https://www.studioemma.com/) called [Optimus](https://github.com/studioemma/magento2-theme-optimus).

I wonder if there are anymore out there like these.

Comment: Great! I will test it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use SASS based version of [Magento 2 Blank theme](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass) with [Gulp](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools)